# Дождаться окончания выполнения метода

Tags: swift

Я хочу чтобы метод класса getPhotos выполнялся до конца, а уже потом код после. Иначе фотографии не отображаются в коллекции. Как можно этого добиться?

```
// MARK: - Text Field Delegate
extension CollectionViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        collectionManager.getPhotos(searchTerm: textField.text!)
        print("finish")
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Это будет работать только в том случае, если в методе `collectionManager.getPhotos` не обновляется UI.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn() -> Bool {
  return DispatchQueue(label: "getPhotos").sync {
    collectionManager.getPhotos(searchTerm: textField.text!)
    print("finish")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
    return true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте эту функцию обьявить в главном потоке и задать первую позицию в очереди